# spring controller return protobuf for specific path

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers

I have a controller which converts the returned object into json
For a specific path "/protobuf" I want it to convert to protobuf, how do I do that ?

```
@RequestMapping(
    method   = RequestMethod.POST,
    value    = { "/{version}/protobuf" },
    consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf" },
    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf" }
)
@ResponseBody
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand well you want your method to return protobuf instead of json.

Can you remove the @ResponseBody

ie

```
@RequestMapping(
    method   = RequestMethod.POST,
    value    = { "/{version}/protobuf" },
    consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf" },
    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf" }
)
```